# Php Pdo database connectivity error

Tags: php, mysql

I have a website hosted by united domains. It was working fine with MySQLi but I changed it to PDO. Now I cannot get the database to work. I've tried changing $host to 127.0.0.1, and to localhost. If I use localhost, I get the error `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory`.

If I use 127.0.0.1 I get `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused`.

I have also tried by changing collation but it still doesn't work. It works perfectly fine on my other domain that is on Hostinger.

```
$host = "localhost"; // I have tried using both 127.0.0.1 and localhost here
$db = "db_name"; //db name goes here
$username = "username"; //username goes here
$password = "password"; //password goes 


try {
    //Creating a PDO instance
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

}catch(\PDOException $e){
    // if connection fails, show PDO error
    echo "Connection Failed: ". $e->getMessage(); 
}
```

Comment: *united domains* probably wants something else than `localhost`

Comment: normaly they give you your username, password and the host of the mysql serveur

Comment: Do you use docker?

Comment: Have you tried adding the port number at the end like so: mysql:host=$servername:PORT_NUMBER; --- Mine is 3307 maybe yours is different but you can try 3307 but the default  is 3306

Comment: I was using "localhost" with mysqli and it was working just fine

Comment: Yes i have tried using port numbers too didn't work

Comment: you need to explicitly set the port, if you get the `[2002] Connection refused` error.

Comment: I am using the exact username, password and the host that united domains provided me

Comment: Yes sir i have tried using explicit port